# CLLocationManager Permissions on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, cllocationmanager, ios-permissions

I currently have an application that uses location services and is working great on devices running iOS5 and above.  However, have been running into inconsistency issues with 4.3.x.

**Problem:**

When installing and running the app for the **FIRST** time, we get the usual 'Allow this app to use Location Services' dialogue to change the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`.  However, when we uninstall the application (from the home screen) and reinstall the app, we never get this prompt again and somehow the OS has cached the users response for this app, despite this app being uninstalled and reinstalled freshly.  On all other versions of iOS, we get the prompt as expected and the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` is set to `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` as expected.

Can anyone tell me why with 4.3 the OS seems to remember the options for the app despite it being uninstalled?  In order to rectify this issue currently, I have to manually reset all Location Services settings on the device through the settings menu.

If you need any information, or code snippets, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a 4.3 limitation and is apparent when running an application on any device iOS 4.3.

Apple must have decided this isn't a bug - which is strange seeing as when a user uninstalls an application, why does the OS remember that users selection of permission for a particular app?

No valid workaround available.  Just have to live with it.